# Resizing text, not bounding box

Tags: text, resize

I am trying to make 8" tall numbers, however when I select the number to be resized, the bounding box is actually bigger than the number. So my bounding box ends up being 8" tall by 4.5" wide, but the number itself is only about 7" tall by 3.75" wide. How do I make that bounding box be the same size as the number? I'm attaching a picture to display my question, I'm not sure if I worded it clearly enough.[image]

Thank you in advance for any help you have!

Answer (score 2):

the bounding box includes the *leading* for the font. (to find out more about what that is, read this wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading )

There are 2 ways to accomplish what you want:

1. put two guidelines spaced 8" apart from each other and size the type to fit between them by grabbing a handle and using shift+drag to resize.
2. Change the type to outlines by selecting it and then choosing **Type > Create Outlines**. After you do that, you can specify the height of the text in the height box on the toolbar.